# How constructor works in private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-specifier

I know there are same question about this topic. But I'm still confused. Please explain how A's class constructor is executing with `obj` even I inherit A's class constructor privately.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        A(){
            cout << "A" << endl;
        }
};
class B:private A{
    public:
        B(){
            cout << "B" << endl;
        }
};
int main(){
    B obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
A
B
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Private inheritance means that all *public and protected base members* become private in the derived class. So `A::A()` is a private in `B`, and thus perfectly accessible from `B::B()`.

What `B::B()` can't use are *private* constructors of `A` (but you don't have any of those):

```
struct A
{
public:
    A();
protected:
    A(int);
private:
    A(int, int);
};

struct Derived : /* access irrelevant for the question */ A
{
    Derived() : A() {}      // OK
    Derived() : A(10) {}    // OK
    Derived() : A(1, 2) {}  // Error, inaccessible
};
```

Comment: can you explain how my given example works? I mean can you show me code of background processing in my given example?

Comment: @LetDoit: I don't quite understand your question. Your definition of `B::B()` implies the default construction of the `A` subobject; it's like you if you had written `B::B() : A() { /* your code */ }`.

Comment: in my example `B( )` implicitly calls the default constructor of A's class? Such as. `B() : A() {  }`

Comment: @LetDoit: Isn't that what I just said?